# Downloading XML fails using NetHTTPClient

Tags: delphi, download

I am using Delphi 10.2.3.

I want to download daily exchange rates from http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml

My design time component setup:

```
NetHTTPClient1.AllowCookies := True;
NetHTTPClient1.HandleRedirects := True;
NetHTTPClient1.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36';

NetHTTPRequest1.MethodString := 'GET';
NetHTTPRequest1.URL := 'http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml';
```

My code is very simple:

```
XML := NetHTTPRequest1.Execute().ContentAsString();
```

What I get back in XML variable is:

```
<html><body><script>document.cookie='sssssss=6ed9ca3asssssss_6ed9ca3a; path=/';window.location.href=window.location.href;</script></body></html>
```

When I try to use a web browser (Opera in my case) I can see correct XML using same URL as above. I could not see what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**:
After reading @NineBerry comments, I used [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to watch each and every packet to the site. That showed me that browser is doing a request for three times before it can actually download XML. Second request, browser adding cookie reference in the response to first request. 3rd request is same as 2ns request.

After investigating below is a working code for me and I am not changing any `TNetHTTPClient.UserAgent` parameter:

```
function DownloadExchangeRates(const URL: string; out XML: string): Boolean;
var
  Cookie: string;
  Path: string;
  AURI: TURI;
  AClient: TNetHTTPClient;
  ARequest: TNetHTTPRequest;
begin
  AClient := nil;
  ARequest := nil;
  try
    AClient := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
    AClient.AllowCookies := True;
    AClient.HandleRedirects := True;

    ARequest := TNetHTTPRequest.Create(nil);
    ARequest.Client := AClient;
    ARequest.Asynchronous := False;
    ARequest.MethodString := 'GET';
    ARequest.URL := URL;
    ARequest.CustomHeaders['Pragma'] := 'no-cache';

    try
      XML := ARequest.Execute().ContentAsString();
      if XML.Length > 5 then
      begin
        if UpperCase(XML.Substring(0, 6)) = '<HTML>' then
        begin
          Cookie := GetCookie(XML);
          AURI := TURI.Create(URL);
          Path := AURI.SCHEME_HTTP + '://' + AURI.Host + '/';
          AClient.CookieManager.AddServerCookie(Cookie, Path);
          AClient.CookieManager.AddServerCookie(Cookie, URL);
          ARequest.CustomHeaders['Referer'] := URL;
          XML := ARequest.Execute().ContentAsString();
          if XML.Length > 5 then
          begin
            if UpperCase(XML.Substring(0, 6)) = '<HTML>' then
            begin
              XML := ARequest.Execute().ContentAsString();
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        Exit(False);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ARequest.Free();
    AClient.Free();
  end;

  Result := (XML.Length > 2) and (XML[2] = '?');
end;
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is illegal. The website uses technology to prevent you from doing what you are not allowed to do.

Comment: The question is asking for ways to illegally circumvent intellectual property protections.

Comment: @NineBerry I highly doubt that it is illegal. It's quite possible to retrieve the XML with a simple request using THTTPClient.

Comment: @NineBerry this information is from a central bank of Israel. XML contains information of daily exchange rates that meant to be publicly accessed. There is nothing illegal here.

Comment: The response you see is typically employed to prevent automatic download of information from a website. It may be triggered for example by making too many requests from the same IP address in a short time or by making a request from an IP range which is specifically limited. Anyway: This is a mechanism used by the website to prevent you from automatically downloading the data. You should contact the website administrator to find out what limits there are and how you can reliably access the information from an automated script.

Comment: The other possibility is that there is a web proxy between your computer and the boi.org.il server that introduces this behaviour. If you are in a corporate or government network, talk with your network administrator to find out if you have a webproxy in your local network which does this.

Comment: I understand all these. On the other hand, my web browser gets XML just fine on same computer I am making tests. That makes me think that there is something I am doing wrong or missing so I fail to read the file.

Comment: The response contains JavaScript code which sets a cookie and then reloads the page. Your Webbrowser will execute this JavaScript code. That's why it works in the Browser. THttpClient cannot execute JavaScript code. You would have to simulate what the JavaScript code is doing. (Extract the cookie values from the response, add it in `NetHTTPClient1.CookieManager` and then try again.)

Comment: @ErtanKüçükoglu Can you use Indy? TIdHTTP is good for this, I can give you an example if you can use TIdHTTP

Comment: @Alberto Miola, it was an TIdHTTP at first place. I changed it to TNetHTTPClient because of mentioned problem. So, for me, same problem exists even using Indy.

Comment: @NineBerry, would you make your comment a reply and I shall accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
uses 
  System.Net.HttpClient;

function TUpdater.DownloadFile(const aURL: string; aStream: TStream): boolean;
var
  vHTTP: THTTPClient;
begin
  Assert(aStream <> nil);
  vHTTP := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
     Result := vHTTP.Get(aURL, aStream).StatusCode = 200;
  finally
    vHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Using that code, I get exactly same XML as in my original post just cookie changes.